# Why won't Gedit save my file the first time I try?

Tags: fedora, gedit

I'm using Gedit on Fedora, and when I try to save, it states that it's unable to, but if I try again, it succeeds. So, it saves only on the second attempt, every time.

Comment: So, you need to press Ctrl+S twice?

Comment: You should probably include a more detailed error message. We need more info to help.

Comment: What version of Fedora is this, and what is the underlying filesystem?

Comment: On the first try I get:
"Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy"
so I click cancel.
On the second it succeeds to save.
It's Fedora15, I'm not sure what fs it is, how can i check?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've fixed it.
It was in a shared folder with VBOX host, now I moved it to a different folder and it was solved.